# ConcurrentModificationException not happening

Tags: java, concurrency, crash

I have the following code:

```
List list = getItems(); //where getItems() returns List<Item>


        do {
            list.add(adPosition);
            adPosition = adPosition + (AD_REPEAT_VALUE + 1);
            adsNumber++;
        } while (adsNumber < MAX_NUMBER_OF_ADS && adPosition < list.size());
```

And from what I know this code should crash with ConcurrentModificationException because the list size is modified. But it doesn't crash. How is this possible?!

Comment: You don't iterate the list, each iteration of your loop is "stand alone" part of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Concurrent Modification` exception is thrown when we are using an iterator on List(or basically iterating the list) object and at same time actual list changes.

Comment: And if I had used a "for" statement it would have crashed?

Comment: No, as nowhere in your code are you iterating on your list, visit the documentation if its a bit hard

Comment: Ok, thanks. It seems I misunderstood this exception. Thanks again :)

Comment: glad to help, accept one of the answers so that others looking for similar problem can identify quickly

Comment: I have to wait for another 2 minutes

Answer (score 2):

Adding elements to a list is perfectly legal. See documentation on [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html): it is thrown when concurrently you add and iterate the list like:

```
Iterator it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    list.add(elem); // ConcurrentModificationException thrown here
}
```